# clear button makes the list in listview become invisible in c#

Tags: c#, listview

i have listview and two buttons; clear and view.

the view button runs perfectly as it should be and when i click the clear button, it does clear as it should.

problem happens after click the clear button, the view button seems does not work. it does not view anything that i want.

same goes when i click the clear button first then i click the view button, it will not view anything. as if the clear button will hold of the data from visible in the listview.

can anyone help me with this?

Below is my code for the clear button.

```
 private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Clear();
        }
```

This is my view button.

```
private void view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
   ListViewItem listviewitem;
   for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
   {
      String words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();
      String[] berjaya = words.Split(new char[] { ',', '[', ']', ' ' }); 
      listviewitem = new ListViewItem(berjaya[43]);
      listviewitem.SubItems.Add(berjaya[41]);
      listviewitem.SubItems.Add(berjaya[1]);
      listviewitem.SubItems.Add(berjaya[45]);
      this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);

      listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

      listView1.View = View.Details;

      foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.listView1.Columns)
          ch.Width = -2;

   }
}
```

for better view, here is my interface of both situation.

[image][image]

the first picture shows that the output when click the view button.

the second picture shows the output when click the clear button. it still print out this way either we click the clear button first or after click the view button. it will not display the data in the listview.

i even tested without using the server like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\myself.xml");
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/main/myself");

        listviewitem = new ListViewItem("a");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("b");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("c");
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add("d");
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);

        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        //show header
        listView1.View = View.Details;

        // Loop through and size each column header to fit the column header text.
        foreach (ColumnHeader ch in this.listView1.Columns)
        {
            ch.Width = -2;
        }
```

still it appears the same like before.

Comment: @yogi: i already put my view code.

Comment: Sara what is `_server` here and did you have tested your view code with breakpoints ? did it goes inside that for loop after clearing listview ?

Comment: @yogi: yes i did. i just edit my post the way i tested. still, it does not work. the clear function seems to make the data to be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Depedant on the code for your View button, you must know that if you want all the items to appear again after you have cleared a ListView, you must add the items back into the Listview, like so:

```
listView.Items.Add("I am being added to the list");
```

Please do post your View button code though to ensure I am answering your question correctly.

Comment: it is not the problem of adding the data, but appearing the data after clicking the clear button. if u could help me with this, im very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      listView1.Items.Clear();
}
```

instead of

```
private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      listView1.Clear();
}
```

`ListView.Clear();` method is used to remove all items as well as columns from a `ListView` but I guess you only want items to be removed, So you should use `ListView1.Items.Clear();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a ListViewItem, adding items manually to a View, accessing directly the controls : all this you should not do.
You should have a DateList Property : an ObservableCollection of your ETA/Priority/date/... object. Then in your ListView you do a binding to this property ItemSource="{Binding DateList}", don't forget to setup the DataContext in the new() or loaded() function of the Window. And then you ONLY operate on DateList in your code behind, adding or removing your data items.
If you don't do like this you will buy yourself more and more problems (like this one : see that a simple operation like clearing breaks your code...)